# Changing activity launch Intent error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I have Changed the activity that I want to run first from `MainActivity` to another. I did this by editing Android manifest and copying:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

To the Activity I want. Now when I run or debug my app on my android device it is successfully installed but it does not automatically launch like before I have to click on the icon and I get the error below and if I run it in emulator the right activity launches only at first installation afterwords it just ignores that activity and always starts `MainActivity`.

Please help.

```
Launching application: com.package/com.package.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "com.package/com.package.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=si.comtron.tronpos/.MainActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=si.comtron.tronpos/.MainActivity } from null (pid=3636, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10104
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2211)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:680)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:270)
at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My whole manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="si.comtron.tronpos" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

<!-- calendar -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />

<!-- camera -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<!-- client -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Authenticator -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Shortcut -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<!-- Wifi -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".bluetooth.DeviceListActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/select_device"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor" />

    <!-- android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" -->
    <activity
        android:name=".BasicDataActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AnalysisActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor" />
    <activity
        android:name=".authorization.AuthenticatorActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/account_register"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor" />
    <activity
        android:name=".authorization.LocalAuthenticatorActivity"
        android:label="@string/account_register"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor" />
    <activity
        android:name=".authorization.SingUpActivity"
        android:label="@string/account_register"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor" />

    <service android:name=".authorization.TronPosAuthenticatorService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>
    <activity
        android:name=".CountryPicker"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UnitActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_unit" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Also, besides posting your complete AndroidManifest.xml, do an `adb uninstall -d com.yourpackage.yourapp` to delete the app from your device and make sure you are using the last version

Comment: @piyushkukadiya manifest added

Answer (score 0):

make sure that only one of the activity has this tag in it

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

or you will confuse the system and android will make two different icon launcher in menu,

and yes uninstall all components from Emulator and from device and reinstall app

Comment: Only one activity has this intent and I have unintalled everyting and reinstalled. Still the same thing.

Comment: clean your project and build it again that should work

Comment: Clean did not help. I edited my question with whole manifest if that helps.